# What forces do Higgs boson carries or exchanges?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, mass, higgs

Without the Higgs field all particles would be traveling at speed of light, so I imagine the electron is interacting with the Higgs field right now. If they are not exchanging electromagnetic forces, then what fundamental force is it?

Comment: A small nugatory quibble: The bulk of your mass, and that of all hadrons, hence  atoms, is due to QCD chiral symmetry breaking, and not interactions with the Higgs.  leptons might travel at the speed of light, but not hadrons, without a Higgs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not exchanging any fundamental forces in the usual sense of "electromagnetism, weak force, strong force, and gravity". These interactions are mediated by other particles. Namely, the photon is the particle responsible for carrying the electromagnetic interaction, the $W^{\pm}$ and $Z$ bosons are responsible for carrying the [weak interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction), and the gluons carry the [strong interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction).

Gravity would be carried by the hypothetical [graviton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton), but it wasn't observed so far (nor is it a part of the [Standard Model of Particle Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), which does not describe gravitation). Due to this difference, I'll no longer consider it in the remaining of this answer.

The Higgs field is a technical necessity of the Standard Model necessary to allow for some of these force-carrying particles to have masses. Namely, the weak bosons are massive and we know this experimentally, but being [gauge bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory), they can't be written as massive particles without running into a few technical trouble (namely, adding mass terms to them would spoil gauge symmetry). The Higgs field is then added to the model to provide a form of [spontaneous symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking), which is a way of bypassing this technical limitation. As a side effect, the Higgs ends up coupling to the fermions (electrons, neutrinos, quarks, etc) of the Standard Model as well with interaction proportional to the particle's mass.

Hence, the Higgs has a different status than the other bosons, and also it couples directly to the fermions. The electron's interaction with the Higgs needs not to be mediated by one of the gauge bosons that carry the fundamental interactions, but rather they interact directly. It is not an electromagnetic interaction, it is something like a "Higgs interaction" (but notice that, as mentioned, this has a different status than the fundamental interactions).

It is worth pointing out that the electron does undergo other interactions beyond electromagnetic and gravitational. For instance, it does interact with the Higgs field and with the weak interactions.

Comment: @annav Thanks for your comment! I updated my answer accordingly. Do you believe this new version solves the issue?

Comment: It is a good answer forr the search engines